# Using unicode for resource file with visual studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, unicode

In visual studio 2010 professionnal,  How do i know if my resource files are encoded in unicode, and if not how do i do that ?

Comment: Are you talking about .resw-files?

Comment: No i'm talking about .rc file

Comment: The solution i found is open the .rc file in notepad++ check the encoding. In Visual studio 2010 look at tools->options->environment->documents, you can tick un box so the files are encoded in Unicode(which one ? :D) if necessary.